# Will a 7 week old kitten stay long-haired?

Tags: cats, breeds, new-pets

I’m looking at getting a kitten, and in particular would love a medium/long-haired cat. I’ve been looking into ragdolls but since have seen this little cutie pop up (see photo). She’s the only one in the litter of six who currently has longer hair, and the breeder advised that both the mother and father are short-haired cats. Is it likely she will lose all her long fur? She is 7 weeks old currently. I know nobody can look into a crystal ball but any advice would be really helpful :) [image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Because we have a very similar question with good answers, your question may be closed. If you feel the linked question is not helpful for you, then please edit your question adding informations WHY the linked one is not helpful for you.

Comment: At least I've never heard of a cat starting out with longer fur and ending up with short fur. Usually it's the opposite. Kittens start off with short fur, then their fur grows in longer, if it's destined to be a long haired cat, that is.

Comment: @Kai I suppose some people could mistake a kitten’s  guard hairs (“fuzzies”) for long hair.